Is it possible to opt out of the validation provided by x:DataType?
So say an element declares an x:DataType, then any invalid binding is a compiler error. If, in some contexts, this isn't wanted, is it possible to discard the protections provided by an outer x:DataType?
I've considered/tried setting x:DataType to "" and "x:Object", however neither worked ("" is invalid syntax and x:Object doesn't seem to be a special case, still resulting in XFC0045 "Binding: Property "Xyz" not found on "System.Object"").
I recognise that (a) the easiest solution would be "don't use x:DataType at all!" and (b) if I'm already using x:DataType in some places, I may as well use it in all places, however I do believe that discarding x:DataType's protections is the best option if possible given the restrictions I'm trying to work within.

I can't understand your question clearly. Did you mean you want the compiler ignore the binding error when you declare the x:DataType and do an invalid binding?

Did you check the official document about the Compiled bindings in XAML.

Can you please provide a specific example of an invalid warning caused by using DataType?

Maybe set it to {x:Null} but I think rather than trying to fight the system you will want to just implement it correctly

If you are trying to pull some dark magic, by making some control like "card", and use if for all kind of different models, that have similar structure, lets say "customer" has property name, but "city" has property name also, with the illusion that it will save you some time and speed up the development process - I advise you to drop the idea now.

Thanks to Gerald Versluis for this answer in the comments - this can be achieved by setting x:DataType={x:Null}.
